# How do I access Context Menus with Python?

Tags: python, interface

I am trying to add a 'menu item' to the 'Set Parent To' context menu. This menu appears when you press 'ctrl+p' while the mouse cursor is in the '3D View'

I cannot find any way to add items to any context menus through python.

I am able to add 'menu items' to any other type of menu.

This `bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_parent.append(menu_function)` works perfectly fine but I would rather have my function listed in this menu specifically.
[image: ContextMenu_SetParentTo]

Are context menus just not currently accessible?

If they are accessible, can someone show me how to add an item to this menu please?

Comment: In this case it's not a context menu rather an 'Operator' menu, see the keymap... I guess there is no way to add a new item to this.

Comment: @brockmann I, actually, already have looked at the keymap but obviously I didn't catch on that the menu was generated by the 'Operator'. Thanks for that clarification. Now I wonder if there is a way to override the function that generates that menu. If not, I'll make a new menu I guess.