# does anybody know the name of that menu so that i can extend it?

Tags: python, rigging, parent

I know how i can extend a menu in python.

Unfortunately i don't know the menu-id/name of this menu:

[image]

Does anybody know it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I access Context Menus with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228615/how-do-i-access-context-menus-with-python) (unable to flag since the suggested dupe has no upvotes or answers)

Comment: Hovering over that menu entry gives "bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='BONE',...)" for the Bone entry if you have Python tooltips enabled under Preference > Interface > Display.

Comment: @Joachim: I think you are right

Comment: @JohnEason: Thanks, but i think this won't work for me.